# How to exclude specific jars from injars during obfuscation using proguard?

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I have many **external** jars inside my **Application\WEB-INF\lib**

Consider **abc.jar** as one of my external jar, which i do not want to obfuscate

So can i exclude as like below using filter in my proguard configuration ?

**-injars C:\Application\WEB-INF\lib(!abc.jar)**

If i do as above for injar option filter means, abc.jar is also getting obfuscated. Please suggest where i am going wrong ? How to avoid obfuscating it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use -injars to specify code that you want to be processed, and -libraryjars to specify underlying code that you want to remain unchanged. Something like this may work:

```
-injars      C:/Application/WEB-INF/lib/mycode.jar
-libraryjars C:/Application/WEB-INF/lib(!mycode.jar;)
```

Note the semi-colon between the jar name filter and the (empty) class name filter.