# Prevent a directory from proguard obfuscation

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

I have gone through several stackoverflow posts regarding proguard obfuscation

[How to keep/exclude a particular package path when using proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard)

[How to make Proguard ignore external libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721397/how-to-make-proguard-ignore-external-libraries)

[How to exclude specific jars from injars during obfuscation using proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057009/how-to-exclude-specific-jars-from-injars-during-obfuscation-using-proguard)

But I did not find answer to exclude a particular directory to prevented from obfuscation.

Directory structure:

```
libs 
      => lib1
               => a.b.c.package
                            A.java
                            B.java
      => lib2
               => d.e.f.package
                            C.java
                            D.java
      => lib3
              => g.h.i.package 
                            E.java
                            F.java
```

Instead of adding multiple lines in `-keep` option with each package name, I would like to exclude entire **libs** package from obfuscation.

Is there any way to stop obfuscation of a particular directory **libs** as shown below?

And is there a way to exclude java run time classes from obfuscation?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line at the top of your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keeppackagenames your.complete.packagename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean directory is the package, then in proguard-rules.pro add the following line:

```
-keep class com.example.something.packageName.** { *; }
```

Comment: I had many sub-directories under a root directory ( say libs)  and actual package name starts from sub-directories